# Asp.net MVC5 application Runtime compilation

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, runtime-compilation

Is there any way to make my asp.net mvc5 applications runtime compilation like angular. In traditional way I change in .cshtml file save and press f5 to refresh running page then I get my change effect on page. But is there any way that can reload my page without pressing f5 in browser as like as angular application do.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax refreshes the current page and gets the data from the server.

As shown in the code: ajax calls the Test action method under the PageLoad controller.

The background code is as follows:

```
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            var actionResult = default(JsonResult);
            var stu = new STU();
            this.UpdateModel(stu);
            var tmp = string.Format("{0}{1} old from {2}", stu.Name, stu.Age, stu.City);
            actionResult = new JsonResult()
            {
               Data = new { Message = tmp }
            };
              Thread.Sleep(5000);
              return actionResult;
        }
```

According to the student information passed by the front desk, return a string to ajax.

```
<form id="student_form">
  <input type="submit" id="sub" value="submit" />
</form>

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#student_form').submit(function() {
     $.ajax({
         // ajax submit code....
     });
         return false;
   });
});
```